# ClassInterfaceTypes mixed in one assembly (AutoDual and none)

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have c# project in which I have some classes declared `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` and other ones `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`.

These classes are COM Visible cause I need to import the type library(.tlb) to Delphi.

When I Import the type library to Delphi, if I create the unit without the "Create component wrapper" enabled, the Delphi packages that use the `AutoDual` types won't recognize them.
However if I create the unit with the wrapper option enabled, the opposite happens, the `ClassInterfaceType.None` classes don't get recognized properly but passes through the `AutoDual` ones.

Any idea? Do I need to have these types in different assemblies?

I'm generating the _TLB.pas files on a 32 bit Windows Server 2003 and compiling using FinalBuilder 7.